# Resample Dataframe Using Exact Start Period

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe that looks like:

```
time
18:00:00.051563    2575.50
18:00:01.023444    2575.50
18:00:02.000000    2575.50
18:00:03.000000    2575.50
18:00:04.000000    2575.50
18:00:05.000000    2575.50
18:00:06.000000    2575.50
18:00:07.000000    2575.50
```

I want to resample into 2 second intervals, with the start interval being `18:00:00.000000`.  But since the first data point in my series is `18:00:00.051563` the resulting buckets also start at `00.051563` instead of `00.00000`.

`df.resample('2S', closed='left', label='left', base=0).mean()`

```
time
18:00:00.051563    2575.317742
18:00:02.051563    2575.427632
18:00:04.051563    2575.674342
18:00:06.051563    2575.902778
18:00:08.051563    2576.287037
18:00:10.051563    2576.392857
18:00:12.051563    2576.416667
18:00:14.051563    2576.164286
18:00:16.051563    2576.100000
```

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem.  I get indices starting at 18:00:00.  version `0.20.3`

Comment: @piRSquared can you post your code?

Comment: `from pandas import Timestamp; pd.Series({Timestamp('2017-10-31 18:00:00.051563'): 2575.5, Timestamp('2017-10-31 18:00:01.023444'): 2575.5, Timestamp('2017-10-31 18:00:02'): 2575.5, Timestamp('2017-10-31 18:00:03'): 2575.5, Timestamp('2017-10-31 18:00:04'): 2575.5, Timestamp('2017-10-31 18:00:05'): 2575.5, Timestamp('2017-10-31 18:00:06'): 2575.5, Timestamp('2017-10-31 18:00:07'): 2575.5}).resample('2S').mean()`

Comment: @piRSquared This helped lead me to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Realizing @piRSquared's code worked as expected I rexamined the data pipeline and realized my `time` column type was a `TimedeltaIndex` which is what caused the unexpected behaviour in resample.

The `TimedeltaIndex` arose from an implicit conversion of time-only strings.

If your problem is anything like mine this might help you:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + df['time'])
```